# Pagenumber in first page when using fancyhr package

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

My problem is, I want numbering on first page, but it always starts from page 2, and I don't know how what I have to change in order to having the page number on the first page, this is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.6pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\iffloatpage{}{My header \\ myHeader}}
    \headsep = 1.5cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\large {\textbf{Testing}\\Purposes\\}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\normalsize
test text

\newpage

This is page number 2...

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to force a first page with numbers in this context?

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.6pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\iffloatpage{}{My header \\ myHeader}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}\thepage}
    \headsep = 1.5cm
}

\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\large {\textbf{Testing}\\Purposes\\}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\normalsize
test text

\newpage

This is page number 2...

\end{document}
```